# gnu ld fail to link .c program

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors, ld

in order to understand the compilation process, I am trying to get an executable of a simple program compiling and linking separately.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello! This is a test prgoram.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

With

> gcc -o hello hello.c

all went OK and produced the desired executable with expected output.

> ldd hello

Produced:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffce53ee000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f923498b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9234d55000)
```

Then tried each step separately:

> cpp -v hello.c > hello.i

To obtain preprocessed output, then,

> gcc -S hello.i

To get assemblercode, then,

> as -o hello.o hello.s

To get object code. Until this step all went apparently OK, but with,

> ld --verbose  -o hello hello.o -lc -l:ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

I got:

```
attempt to open hello.o succeeded
hello.o
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so succeeded
opened script file //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
opened script file //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a succeeded
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 succeeded
-l:ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400280
```

Apparently it succeded to open both libraries and object file, but failed to link them all.

Versions:

> gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)
>   GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1

Am I missing something (a library, an option, etc) in this schema?.

Regards.

Comment: Try `gcc -v hello.c` to see what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You have to build and link your program with `stubstart.S` which provides `_start` entry point like below

```
.globl _start

_start:
    call main
    movl $1, %eax
    xorl %ebx, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

```sh
$ gcc -c stubstart.S -o stubstart.o
$ ld --verbose -o hello hello.o stubstart.o -lc -l:ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Comment: Not entirely correct. What is really needed is some [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) which does *a lot more* than your code above

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Maybe your are right. I have provided the minimum for simple examples like OP posted.

Comment: I like this answer because it shows what the problem is at a more "low level" and hints at the deeper explanation for *why* GCC is linking additional "magic" files. I think it could be better if it went into more detail about why it works this way (the OS actually calls `_start` and not `main`, and gcc/libc implements common runtime initialization and teardown logic in those special files), and giving some guidance into when you might want or prefer to write your own `_start` stub vs. just linking the common runtime files provided by your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I use verbose as mentioned by @melpomene, and finally got desired outcome with the collect2 wrapper as:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/collect2 -plugin
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/liblto_plugin.so
>   -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccVm3XOm.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro -o hello /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o
>   -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../.. hello.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
>   --verbose

It was needed crt libraries as mentioned latter.